# Z3 C++ API yields "unknown" while binary on serialized output yields "unsat"

Tags: c++, z3

When I build up a certain set of constraints using the Z3 C++ API I get "**unknown**" in response.  However, if I serialize the `z3::solver` object using operator<<() and pass the output to the z3 binary, it yields "**unsat**" as expected.  Interestingly enough, if I use `z3::solver::to_smt2()` instead of operator<<(), the Z3 binary outputs "**unknown**".

Why is this occurring?  How can I get Z3 using the C++ API to "see" what the standalone binary "sees"?

I've uploaded the serialized constraint files to pastebin in case that helps

Using operator<<(): http://pastebin.com/uRfP90W5

Using to_smt2(): http://pastebin.com/6qQ6WsHN

Answer (score 0):

The example uses non-linear arithmetic, so ends up using an incomplete solver in spite of the fact that it is non-linear arithmetic over the reals. You can query why z3 returns unknown using the command

(get-info :reason-unknown)

after the (check-sat) call. It will then say:

(:reason-unknown "smt tactic failed to show goal to be sat/unsat (incomplete (theory arithmetic))")

Digging into the formula we see a couple of multiplications between function applications. There is no complete integration in Z3 of non-linear reasoning on reals and formulas using free functions.

Comment: Got it, but why would one representation (output of operator<<()) be solvable while another (the output of to_smt2()) is not?